# Developing Android app on both Linux and Windows host

Tags: android, windows, linux

My main developing phase is done on a Ubuntu machine.
The project is shared on the cloud by Dropbox.
I'd like to access to the project on other PC but, since it is a Windows PC, i receive some errors, first of all, the project path!!

Is there a way, or some guideline, to allow to develop the same project on Linux and Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Dropbox, use a public version controls service (github, assembla) (or private + vpn etc.) and checkout the project on as many workstations as you want. Make you sure you don't check in IDE Specific files like Eclipse's '.classpath' etc.